# No Manifest Attribute when running jar file that contains SpringBoot

Tags: java, email, intellij-idea, encoding, jar

I am creating a small emailing application that runs within a console using java and springboot. After creating the Jar within intellij using Artifacts - Build I attempt to run the Jar using command prompt to get greeted with 'no main manifest attribute', below are my manifest.mf and my pom.xml. How can I fix this issue?

[image]
[image]

I am new to springboot and the youtube videos don't give a clear enough understanding on where to actually put certain things into your pom.xml or manifest.mf

(MAVEN)

Comment: Spring boot requires specialized jar configuration/packaging, see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-run-maven-vs-executable-jar. Use Maven, not IntelliJ IDEA artifacts.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml file
In the plugin with groupid org.springframework.boot
Add a configuration tag if not there yet
In the configuration tag add the tag mainClass where you specify the full classname

Next, under configurations add /executions/execution/goals/goal repackage

This will re-package your jar and add the manifest file including your runnable class with the main method

An example
[Maven POM Build tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg5Sy.png)

Comment: Can you literally type where to put it